# Equals method of a linked list not working

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am having trouble implementing the remove method in the List class. I am first writing the objects out into a file, then I am retrieving those objects and putting them inside a linked list. However, when I try to check for equality by going over the entire linked list I get not matches even though I know for sure that object is in there. I can't even get .equals to work it seems.

```
package ProjectOne;

public class List<T> {
    private LLNode<T> list;
    private int numberOfNodes = 0;
    private LLNode<T> location;
    private LLNode<T> previous;
    protected boolean found;
    public List() {
        list = null;
    }
    public void add(T element) {
        if (numberOfNodes == 0) {
            list = new LLNode<T>(element);
            numberOfNodes++;
        }
        else {  
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(element);
        newNode.setLink(list);
        list = newNode;
        }
    }


    public void find(T target) {
        location = list;
        found = false;
        while(location !=null) {
            System.out.println(target.equals(location.getInfo()));
            if(location.getInfo().equals(target)) {
                found = true;
                return;
            }
            else {
                previous = location;
                location = location.getLink();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(T element) {
        this.find(element);
            if(found) {
                if(list == location) list = list.getLink();
                else previous.setLink(location.getLink());
            }
            return found;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }



    public String toString() {
        LLNode<T> currentNode = list;
        String info = "";
        while(currentNode !=null) {
            info +=currentNode.getInfo();
            currentNode = currentNode.getLink();
        }
        return info;
    }

}
```

These are one of many objects I am writing out to the file

```
 Patient p1 = new Patient("Alex", "1123 metropolitan", new Date("11/20/1997"));
p1.setFirstVisit(new Date("11/20/1997"));
p1.setHeight(72);
p1.setLastVisit(new Date("11/20/1997"));
p1.setWeight(200);
out.writeObject(p1);

Patient p2 = new Patient("John", "200 avenue of americas", new Date("12/20/1999"));
p2.setFirstVisit(new Date("11/11/2005"));
p2.setHeight(5);
p2.setLastVisit(new Date("11/21/2010"));
p2.setWeight(150);
out.writeObject(p2);

Patient p3 = new Patient("Sarah", "Park avenue", new Date("09/07/1960"));
p3.setFirstVisit(new Date("05/11/1977"));
p3.setHeight(75);
p3.setLastVisit(new Date("01/21/2017"));
p3.setWeight(110);
out.writeObject(p3);

Patient p4 = new Patient("Malcolm", "56street", new Date("05/28/1977"));
p4.setFirstVisit(new Date("01/11/1990"));
p4.setHeight(75);
p4.setLastVisit(new Date("8/21/2016"));
p4.setWeight(155);
out.writeObject(p4);
```

However, when I call `System.out.println(list.remove(p1));`
I get the output
false
false
false
false
false
with the last being the return result of the method and the first four just trying to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you override equals and hashcode methods in Patient class.